# LAG() function in sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have looked at a few other questions regarding this problem, we are trying to get a stored procedure working that contains the LAG() function, but the machine we are now trying to install an instance on is SQL 2008 and we can't use it

```
SELECT se.SetID,SetName,ParentSetId,      
qu.QuestionID,qu.QuestionText,qu.QuestionTypeID,qu.IsPublished,qu.IsFilter,      
qu.IsRequired,qu.QueCode,qu.IsDisplayInTable,      
Case when (LAG(se.ParentSetId) OVER(ORDER BY se.ParentSetId) <> ParentSetId) then 2 else 1 end level , 
QuestionType   
FROM  tblSet se      
LEFT join tblQuestion qu on qu.SetID=se.SetID        
Inner join tblQuestionType qt on qt.QuestionTypeID=qu.QuestionTypeID and qt.IsAnswer=1      
where CollectionId=@colID and se.IsDeleted=0       
order by  se.SetID
```

What I've tried so far (edited to reflect Zohar Peled's) suggestoin

```
SELECT se.SetID,se.SetName,se.ParentSetId,      
qu.QuestionID,qu.QuestionText,qu.QuestionTypeID,qu.IsPublished,qu.IsFilter,      
qu.IsRequired,qu.QueCode,qu.IsDisplayInTable, 
(case when row_number() over (partition by se.parentsetid
                              order by se.parentsetid
                             ) = 1
      then 1 else 2
 end) as level,
QuestionType 
FROM  tblSet se
left join tblSet se2 on se.ParentSetId = se2.ParentSetId -1
LEFT join tblQuestion qu on qu.SetID=se.SetID
Inner join tblQuestionType qt on qt.QuestionTypeID=qu.QuestionTypeID and qt.IsAnswer=1      
where se.CollectionId=@colID and se.IsDeleted=0       
order by  se.SetID
```

it does not seem to be bringing out all of the same records when I run them side by side and the level value seems to be different also

I have put in some of the outputs into a HTML formatted table from the version containing LAG() (the first results) then the second is the new version, where the levels are not coming out the same

https://jsfiddle.net/gyn8Lv3u/

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful to check what is different here.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a new instance of SQL Server 2008? 2008 is now completely out of support. `LAG` is, however,  available in every supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: `LAG` can be implemented with a self-join on a `ROW_NUMBER()` (`JOIN t t2 ON t.c + 1 = t2.c`), which is supported from 2005 onwards. This tends to be less efficient than `LAG`, though, which is of course one of the reasons it was added.

Comment: Unless `se.ParentSetId` is null, `se.ParentSetId <> se.ParentSetId -1` will always be true.

Comment: @Larnu This is a install on another clients machine that is currently running 2008, we are planning on getting them to run 2016, but when we will finally get the go ahead to do that is anybody's guess.

Answer (score 1):

`LAG()` can be implemented using a self-join as Jeroen wrote in his comment, or by using a correlated subquery. In this case, it's a simple `lag()` so the correlated subquery is also simple:

```
SELECT se.SetID,SetName,ParentSetId,      
qu.QuestionID,qu.QuestionText,qu.QuestionTypeID,qu.IsPublished,qu.IsFilter,      
qu.IsRequired,qu.QueCode,qu.IsDisplayInTable,      
Case when (
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 ParentSetId
        FROM tblSet seInner
        WHERE seInner.ParentSetId < se.ParentSetId
        ORDER BY seInner.ParentSetId DESC
    )    
    <> ParentSetId) then 2 else 1 end level , 
QuestionType   
FROM  tblSet se      
LEFT join tblQuestion qu on qu.SetID=se.SetID        
Inner join tblQuestionType qt on qt.QuestionTypeID=qu.QuestionTypeID and qt.IsAnswer=1      
where CollectionId=@colID and se.IsDeleted=0       
order by  se.SetID
```

If you had specified an offset it would be harder do implement using a correlated subquery, and a self join would make a much easier solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, your answer seemed to bring out the same outputted values, but the only problem I'm having is the level value. I've added the outputs into a jsfiddle in the original post

Comment: If you could edit your question to provide a minimized (and preferably simplified) set of sample data a DDL and DML (create table and insert statements) as well as expected results, then I would probably be able to use that to give you a more correct answer.

Comment: I've put a cut down version (columns) of it in the original post in a jsfidlle html table format of the results, none of this was originally written by me so I'm trying to figure out whats going on myself atm

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't help very much. sqlfiddle will help a lot more.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68a72

This is the schema of the tables as soon as I include the data the size becomes too big to use in sqlfiddle

Comment: This is a bit too much information. If you can provide a [mcve] (emphasis on Minimal) that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and desired results would help.  This construct:

```
(case when (LAG(se.ParentSetId) OVER(ORDER BY se.ParentSetId) <> ParentSetId) then 2 else 1
 end) as level
```

is quite strange.  You are lagging by the only column used in the `order by`.  That makes sense.  But then you are comparing the value to the same column, implying that there are duplicates.

If you have duplicates, then `order by se.ParentSetId` is unstable.  That is, the "previous" row is indeterminate because of the duplicate values being ordered.  You can run the query twice and get different results.

I am guessing you want one row with the value `1` for each parent set id.  If so, then in either database, you would use:

```
(case when row_number() over (partition by se.parentsetid
                              order by se.parentsetid
                             ) = 1
      then 1 else 2
 end) as level
```

This also has the problem with an unstable ordering.  You can fix this by changing the `order by` to what you really want.